# Running Migration with ruby on rails and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working through the [Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Ruby-Rails-3-Essential-Training/55960-2.html). I've created a new database and granted privileges to the local host. I then generated a few migrations but when I try to run the migrations I get:

> error: Access denied for user 'simple_cms'@localhost' .

I have granted privileges to localhost and generating the migrations went smoothly but for some reason I can't seem to fix this error. I have made sure my `database.yml` is configured correctly but I still have the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DB doesn't have the needed permissions for the `simple_cms` user that you've defined in your `database.yml` file.  Open a `mysql -u root` console and run:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR simple_cms@localhost;
```

And see what permissions they have, they'll be missing some that they need like `CREATE` or `DROP` or something related to your migrations.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I ran SHOW GRANTS FOR simple_cms@localhost; and got back:  GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'simple_cms'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*ADCB311F8421434234234' GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES ON 'simpl_cms_development' TO 'simple_cms@localhost'     It says the grants are there but I have no idea where it got that long password from.

Comment: Great, so you were able to fix your underlying issue?

Comment: I actually just took off the two passwords that I put on and that fixed the problem.  I'm going to link you to another question I'm stuck on if you have time to look at it.

Comment: Okay I accepted it. Currently I'm trying to set up a name scope. In my subject.rb file I'm following along with my instructor and inserted the line: scope :visible, where(:visible => true)   but from my rails console when I write subjects = Subject.visible  I get an ArgumentError that says 'the scope body needs to be callable'  Any ideas about this?  Would you like me to post this as a formal question?

Comment: Yes, post it as a question.